# Full register access meaning

Tags: embedded, cpu, cpu-registers, msp430, status-register

I am working on the MSP430 microcontroller and was going through its architecture. In the user guide, under its features tab, there is a statement like this -  "***Full register access including program counter (PC), status register (SR), and stack pointer (SP)***". I was under the impression that the CPU always has access to all the registers irrespective of the architecture.

My understanding of the statement may be wrong. Can anyone explain me what it means exactly?

Comment: Since these are named as ordinary registers (PC=R0, SR=R2, SP=R1), I suspect it merely means that they are not treated as *special* registers only operated on by special instructions. I.e., "full access" means orthogonal access or undifferentiated access. You might be interested in Area51's [Embedded Systems Programming and Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems-programming-and-design). [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) currently takes on some embedded systems questions.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430):

> The processor contains 16 16-bit registers, of which 4 are dedicated to special purposes: R0 is the program counter, R1 is the stack pointer, R2 is the status register, and R3 is a special register called the constant generator, providing access to 6 commonly used constant values without requiring an additional operand. R3 always reads as 0 and writes to it are ignored. R4 through R15 are available for general use.

In other words, "full access" in this case means not just using `jmp`-type instructions to be able to jump to a new location, but also allowing something like `xor r0, #1234` to directly (and probably fatally) modify the program counter.

Ditto for the other special registers, except `R3`, the constant generator and the only one of the four not mentioned in your quote. While all the instructions could *operate* on that register, it ignores writes and generates various fixed values on read (`-1..2`, use of `R2` can also give you `4` and `8`) depending on the addressing mode used.

---

That may seem a little strange but it's not the strangest I've ever seen. For *that,* you would have to investigate the RCA1802A CPU which, like the MPS430 had "general purpose" registers for specific functions but you could actually *choose* at run time which should be the program counter or stack pointer. It actually *had* no `call` or `ret` instructions, instead it used a standard call and return technique (SCRT) to emulate it.